# Can not write permanent cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I experimented the [permanent cookies shortcut with Rails 3.0](http://m.onkey.org/2010/2/5/signed-and-permanent-cookies-in-rails-3) (and Ruby 1.9.2) but I can't write in this hash.
I try with the following code :

```
cookies.permanent[:last_used_expiration_delay] = @snippet.expiration_delay
```

But the hash remains empty (here is the YAML dump) :

```
 --- !map:ActionDispatch::Cookies::PermanentCookieJar {}
```

Basic cookies works well, so I can specify the expiration date manually with the old syntax but I would like to use the cool new stuff of Rails 3.

Is there something to do for permanent cookies to work properly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my response: `cookies.permanent` is only used to write. To read, simply look the key in `cookies` hash.